# How to calculate the changed line by git?

Tags: git, github, logging

When I use `git log - -stat`, I can get the “file changed, addition and deletion”. However, I want to calculate how many line changed. For example:

```
git log --stat
-  Print “hello world”;
-  int a;
-  int b;
-  String name;
-  print "a"
+  Print “Hello, World!”
1 file changed, 1 addition, 5 deletions.
```

It’s 1 modified place, but Git just tells me there is 1 addition and 5 deletions. I want to get:

```
git log --stat
-  Print “hello world”;
-  int a;
-  int b;
-  String name;
-  print "a"
+  Print “Hello, World!”
1 file changed, 0 addition, 4 deletions, 1 modify
```

How could I calculate the number of modified lines with Git automatically?

I have try `git log -p` , it shows like:

```
git log -p
-  Print “hello world”;
-  int a;
-  int b;
-  String name;
-  print "a"
+  Print “Hello, World!”
```

So, I need to check it one by one. Does git have the method to calculate the changed lines?

Answer (score 0):

As far as Git's internal diff algorithm is concerned, no line ever *changes*.  It's either there, or not there.  If it's not there and it was before, it was deleted.  If it was not there before and is now, it was inserted.  If it was and still is there, it is unchanged.

There are other algorithms, and post-processors for Git's `diff` output, that will attempt to find "similar" lines in the deleted/added sections and show them as changes within the line.  But Git itself simply does not do that.

(The reason is that for performance, Git treats each line as a single symbol.  The symbol itself may ignore white space or have a few other special treatments.  You can also have Git treat each "word" as a symbol, so that it compares one word at a time and produces a word-by-word diff.  This all feeds into one of the four differencing engines inside Git.  For more on this, see the last section of chapter 3 of my unfinished [book](http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf).)